# Unit testing react component function

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs

I'm writing a web application using `react`. I am not very familiar with client tests, so I'm still trying to figure out how to unit test my components.

I have seen in `react` docs that they offer the `Test Utilities` to test custom UI components, but I didn't find a way to test functions inside my component.

I have a form in which I want to validate the fields, lets say validate the email address. How can I test the functionality of this method? From what I have seen, people just test the UI component itself.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit convoluted, but here's an example that uses [skin-deep](https://github.com/glenjamin/skin-deep) to test functions inside a react component.

Component file:

```
export default React.createClass({
  validate(input) {
    return true
  },
  render() {
    if (validate(this.props.input)) {
      return <div>Valid!</div>
    }
    return <div>Not Valid!</div>
  }
})
```

Test file:

```
import React from 'react'
import sd from 'skin-deep'
import Component from 'Component.jsx'

let tree = sd.shallowRender(React.createElement(Component, {}))
const instance = tree.getMountedInstance()

// Now you can run tests on instance functions.
assert instance.validate(foo) === true
```

We've been putting functions we want to test outside of the React components to avoid doing this.

Comment: Another option is to keep testable logic separate from React components altogether, but if the logic is tightly coupled anyways then I don't think there's a strong reason to separate them.

Comment: Yeah I'd like to keep the logic in the component if possible. Here is what I am using now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284724/unit-test-a-react-component-function-that-depends-on-defaultprops-being-set